# Promoting a task branch to main branch in Branch per Task branching strategy

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

In Branch per Task branching strategy, is there any reason not to promote a task branch into the main branch and just delete the old main branch if the original main branch has not been modified after the task branch was created?

In other words, create a task branch as a copy of the main branch, work on that task branch and when the task is completed just delete the original main branch and make the task branch the main branch giving it the exact same name the original main branch had.

Finally, how would this affect the copies of the original main branch other developers may have on their machines? Would they be able to use 'Get Latest' to get the updated code created within the task branch or would they have to delete the local copy of the original main branch and get the new main branch from TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't do that. It will make it much harder to properly get your history on items in the old MAIN branch. Any releases that were originally made against the MAIN branch will be hartd to retrieve and you might get unexpected "Do you want to undelete file xyz" messages.

Any other branches that are linked to the old MAIN branch will not be able to merge into the new one without doing a baseless merge.

And all of this to not have to do a Merge? This merge will be flawless and completely automatic if the old main branch hasn't changed. TFS will see that there are no conflicting changes and the whole process should be a 2 click experience.

1. Merge
2. Check in

Comment: That's exactly what I was forgetting, good thing I was smart enough to ask... It's just that I'm not at all happy with how TFS merge works so I thought I'd save myself some grief...

Comment: Remember that you can configure another merge tool in Visual studio when you don't like the default one. The experience is also greatly improved with Visual studio 2012 should you not already be using that.